# Is letting my mostly blind dog sniff everything I'm holding teasing her?

Tags: dogs, senior-pet

The family Border collie is pushing 14 and her vision has deteriorated quickly. Ever since her vision got bad, she has had the tendency to try to sniff whatever anyone is holding when they come over to pet her. I figure she's trying to figure out what we have, so I always let her sniff whatever I've got, whatever it is. And before you ask, I don't walk up to her with food I don't intend to give her.

I letting her sniff stuff she won't be interesting in teasing her, or am I just allowing her to know what's going on around her?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't teasing at all - it's actually very sweet of you.  She can't see the world around her, so she has to rely on other senses. You're just giving her the opportunity to understand her surroundings in the best way she can.  If anything, it would be mean to withhold this kind of information from her.

Basically, she's being curious, and you are making sure that her curiosity pays off.  There is nothing cruel about helping your baby keep track of what's going on around her.  She appreciates your help, I'm sure.  You sound like a great doggy parent.